# Redirect 301 with params

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am redirecting traffic between old web and new web and I need to redirect 301 from `/hotel.php?hotel=lasvegas&lng=es` to `http://www.new-web.com/hotel-las-vegas/`

How could be possible from htaccess?
I have tried

```
Rewriterule ^hotel\.php\?hotel=lasvegas\&lng=es http://www.new-web.com/hotel-las-vegas/ [L,R=301]
```

I think my error is at regular expression. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /hotel\.php\?hotel=lasvegas&lng=es [NC]
RewriteRule ^ hotel-las-begas? [R=302,L,NE]

# internal forward from pretty URL to actual one
RewriteRule ^hotel-las-vegas/?$ hotel.php?hotel=lasvegas&lng=es [L,QSA,NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

it's very important that you insert best code of redirect 301 in best  place of htaccess. for example :
http://www.abartazeha.com/
we replace abartazeha.com instead of abartazeha.ir

...

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^olddomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.olddomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```